# Are there matching upper bounds?

Tags: approximation

When reading about approximation algorithms, I often find the terms "matching lower bounds". As I understand, these means to provide examples where the approximation algorithm matches the proved bound___proving that the algorithm achieves the best possible approximation ratio. Often, the approximation algorithm solves a minimization problem. What if the approximation algorithm solves a maximization problem? Are they called "matching upper bounds"?

Comment: I'm not sure about your interpretation of "matching lower bound", but matching upper bounds are the counterparts of matching lower bounds when switching minimization and maximization.

Comment: A matching lower bound is to give an instance of the minimization problem for which the algorithm attains the approximation ratio. Isn't it?

Comment: Right, but this is a bad example for your algorithm, whereas you wrote "best possible approximation ratio". You probably meant that the the bound on the approximation ratio that you prove is best possible (i.e., tight).

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. I meant best possible for the algorithm. So I can say matching upper bound if the problem is a maximization one?

Comment: Both phrases, matching upper bound and matching lower bound, are in common use.